# Rotate an array with weekday names as keys to start with tomorrow

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, rotation

I have the following array:

```
[
     [
         'schedules' => [
             'monday' => 1,
             'tuesday' => 1,
             'wednesday' => 1,
             'thursday' => 1,
             'friday' => 1,
             'saturday' => 0,
             'sunday' => 1,
         ]
    ]
]
```

I'd like to rotate the elements of this array with the first key being the tomorrow. Let's say today was Wednesday, I'd want my array to look like this:

```
[
     [
         'schedules' => [
             'thursday' => 1,
             'friday' => 1,
             'saturday' => 0,
             'sunday' => 1,
             'monday' => 1,
             'tuesday' => 1,
             'wednesday' => 1,
         ]
    ]
]
```

I already have the weekday available (e.g. a string 'thursday'). It gets passed into the function that I'm working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you convert the day to a number 0-6 you can `array_shift` and `array_push` that many times to move the previous days to the end of the array.

Comment: you have the simplest solution for my case. best answer goes to you if you can tell me how to get the day, as a number (0-6) of the 'current tomorrow'

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... `date('N')%7` will do that for you. N returns a number 1-7, so `date('N')%7` will be the the next day in our 0-6 numbering.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php). You can compare dates in the callback function described in the link.

For example:

```
function compare($a, $b) { 
  date(strtotime($a)) - date(strtotime($b)); 
}

uksort($array, "compare");
```

Here's [proof of it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C9ACD6)

Comment: How does it take into account the OPs restriction of "sort the elements of this array with the first key being the [week]day [of] tomorrow"?

Comment: The code I used below is also a uksort, but with a small tweak to cater for the 'sort from today onwards...' request.

Comment: @Martin, don't you need to use `return` in the `compare` function? Also, why can't you just use `strtotime($a) - strtotime($b)`?

Comment: There is NO WAY that this works.  This is 100% teaching researchers to code incorrectly.  Why are there upvotes on this answer?  Even if did work, it is even ignoreing the OP's requirements!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the day of the week via the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.  Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so forth.

```
$weekday = date("w");
```

Then, I suggest using the [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function to sort the array relative to its keys, which takes a callback function as a sorting guideline.

```
uksort($schedules, function ($a, $b) use ($weekday) {
    // convert each day to a number 0-6 and compare to $weekday
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this incomplete answer.  I can't see how uksort is an ideal technique here.

Answer (score 2):

This Answer allows which Day of the Week to start at, and dynamically handles how days are labeled.

This is simply an improved solution using [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php), [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
function sort_days( $term1, $term2 ) {
    $weekdays = array( 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat' );
    foreach ( $weekdays as $key => $value ) {
        $weekdays[ $key ] = date( 'N', strtotime( $value ) );
    }

    $term1_time = date( 'N', strtotime( strtolower( $term1 ) ) );
    $term2_time = date( 'N', strtotime( strtolower( $term2 ) ) );

    return array_search( $term1_time, $weekdays ) - array_search( $term2_time, $weekdays );
}
```

Sorting keys with [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

```
$uk_days = array(
    'thursday'  => 1,
    'monday'    => 1,
    'saturday'  => 1,
    'wednesday' => 1,
    'sunday'    => 1,
    'friday'    => 1,
    'tuesday'   => 1,
);
uksort($uk_days, "sort_days");
var_dump($uk_days);
```

Sorting keys with [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$u_days = array(
    'thursday',
    'monday',
    'saturday',
    'wednesday',
    'sunday',
    'friday',
    'tuesday',
);
usort($u_days, "sort_days");
var_dump($u_days);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this to achieve this

```
$week = [
    'sunday',
    'monday',
    'tuesday',
    'wednesday',
    'thursday',
    'friday',
    'saturday',
];

  $day = date('w'); // weekday as integer(3 for Wednesday)

  for ($i=0; $i <= $day ; $i++) {
    array_push($week, array_shift($week));
  }

  $result = $week;
```

Result (if today is Wednesday):

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => thursday
        [1] => friday
        [2] => saturday
        [3] => sunday
        [4] => monday
        [5] => tuesday
        [6] => wednesday
    )
```

Comment: This does not represent the OP's input data.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a list in the correct order, which you can grab through the DateTime class. Then, as you loop over the old array, use the correct order as the key to sort the array, like so:

```
function sort_by_weekday( $input_array) {
    $now = new DateTime( "tomorrow", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
    $interval = new DateInterval( 'P1D'); // 1 Day interval
    $period = new DatePeriod( $now, $interval, 7); // 7 Days

    $sorted_array = array();
    foreach( $period as $day) {
        $weekday = strtolower( $day->format( 'l'));

        foreach( $input_array as $key => $value) { 
            $sorted_array[ $key ][ $weekday ] = $value[ $weekday ]; 
        }
    }
    return $sorted_array;
}
```

You can see it working in [the demo](http://viper-7.com/mdVv2f).

Answer (score 1):

If you combine a [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) with a simple function, this is a surprisingly easy solution.

Obviously turning the day name strings into ints is needed, but if the day is prior to the current weekday, simply add seven to the variable, that will guarantee that the array is sorted as 'after' even if the day of the week would imply otherwise.

```
<?php

    $a='sunday'; // Example Input
    $b='saturday'; // Example Input

    function funnyDateCompare($a, $b)
    {
        $a=date('w',strtotime($a));
        $b=date('w',strtotime($b));
        if($a<=date('w'))
        {
            $a+=7;
            // First value is less than or equal to today. 
            // Adding 7 to the answer.
        }
        return ($a - $b);
    }

    uksort($array, "funnyDateCompare")
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution which does not cast the days to a date/time type, but instead uses a closure and uksort. Essentially, every key passed to uksort is compared against the position of the "tomorrow" key, and if it is "before" tomorrow, it is "promoted" into the future (`+= 7`), then a simple comparison result is used.

## edited for performance:

Edits motivated by comment by @nickb (thanks!)

```
<?php

function sortedWithNext($days, $tomorrow) {
    $index_dictionary = array_combine(array_keys($days), range(0,6));
    $index_of_tomorrow = $index_dictionary[$tomorrow];
    $compare_function = function($k1, $k2) use ($index_dictionary, $index_of_tomorrow) {
         $index_of_k1 = $index_dictionary[$k1];
         $index_of_k2 = $index_dictionary[$k2];
         if($index_of_k1 < $index_of_tomorrow) 
           $index_of_k1 += 7;
        if($index_of_k2 < $index_of_tomorrow) 
           $index_of_k2 += 7;
        return $index_of_k1 - $index_of_k2;
    };
    uksort($days, $compare_function);
    return $days;
}




$daysPool = array(
'monday'=>1,
'tuesday'=>1,
'wednesday'=>1,
'thursday'=>1,
'friday'=>0,
'saturday'=>1,
'sunday'=>1,
);

$tomorrow = 'thursday';

$sortedDays = sortedWithNext($daysPool, $tomorrow);

var_dump($sortedDays);
```

## performance notes

I tested using 100,000 iterations, this method spends roughly 2.2e-5 seconds to sort the array. The curious will check the first version of this answer to find a less performant version which took about twice as long, 5.5e-5 seconds.

Comment: Since `array_search` is O(n) and you're repeatedly calling both `array_search` and `array_keys` in a callback for sorting, this is likely not very efficient at all.

Comment: That's a fairly easy refactor (at lease one of them...)

Comment: And with another small refactor, all heavy functions have been removed from the closure; thanks for the input, @nickb :-)

Comment: Hi Chris, your answer helped me alot in a plugin that i was writing. However, i am getting a warning PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements. Can you tell me why is it so. I have checked the size of both arrays and they are 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. it will sort days based on current day.

```
    $days = array("Friday","Thursday","Wednesday","Tuesday");
    $days = array_combine($days,$days);
    
    //loop the days and check the next day
    foreach($days as $k => $dd){
        
        //check next day name & increment current date with +1
        $current_dt = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("next day", strtotime($current_dt)));
        $days_name = date("l", strtotime($current_dt));    
        
        // if day name exists in array, push in seperate array
        if(!empty($days[$days_name])){
            $arrSortedDays[] = $days_name;
        }
    }
    
    //check if currnet day fall today, push it in array to last element.
    if(!empty($days[date("l")])){
        $arrSortedDays[] = date("l");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a circular order in the subarray data so there is no requirement to sort by comparing each entry against each other.

The most direct solution (that I know of) is to:

1. Find the correct position to cut the array into two parts, then
2. Remove the first part and reattach it after the second part.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TUPEn))

```
$newStart = 'thursday';
foreach ($array as &$entry) {
    $position = array_search(
        $newStart,
        array_keys($entry['schedules'])
    );
    if ($position) {
        $entry['schedules'] += array_splice(
            $entry['schedules'],
            0,
            $position
        );
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

The condition ensures that no element rotation is performed if the targeted key is not found (`false`) or is already in first position (`0`).

`array_search()` is efficient because it halts iterating as soon as it finds its first match.

I do not endorse any of the earlier answers which recommend:

- `uksort()` -- this has greater computational complexity, not to mention the additional overhead of function calls in the custom function body.
- looping -- iterated function calls are unnecessarily expensive and represent a less elegant / brute force technique. A loop with a break condition and no iterated function calls would not be so bad.
- changing the OP's input data to better suit an alternative solution -- this is unnecessarily admitting defeat.

My solution happens to be suitable as a utility function because it does not rely on any date-related data/logic.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `array_slice` and `array_merge` will do the trick.

```
'week' => [
   'monday' => 1,
   'tuesday' => 1,
   'wednesday' => 1,
   'thursday' => 1,
   'friday' => 1,
   'saturday' => 0,
   'sunday' => 1,
         ]
// get today's index, like Wednesday will be 3
$day = date('w')

// Get the days until today
$previous = array_slice($week, 0, $day); // ["mon","tue","wed"]

// Get remaining days in week
$coming = array_slice($week, $day); //  ["thu","fri","sat","sun",]

array_merge($coming, $previous);//["thu","fri","sat","sun","mon","tue","wed"]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me, just a simple loop:

```
$array = array();

$month = date('m');
$day = date('d');
$year = date('Y');

for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++){
    $array[] = date('l',mktime(0,0,0,$month,($day+$i),$year));
}
```

Output array looks like: (If today is a tuesday)

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'Wednesday',
    (int) 1 => 'Thursday',
    (int) 2 => 'Friday',
    (int) 3 => 'Saturday',
    (int) 4 => 'Sunday',
    (int) 5 => 'Monday',
    (int) 6 => 'Tuesday'
)
```

Comment: This unexplained answer does not represent the OP's challenge.